# Python merger data from two text files and storing it in a seprate text file

Tags: python, file

I have 2 text files named text1.txt and text2.txt with the following data:-

```
text1.txt
1
2
3
4
5

text2.txt
sam
Gabriel
Henry
Bob
Bill
```

I want to write a python scripting reading both the text files and displaying/writing the result in a third text filed, lets call it result.txt in the following format:-

```
1@sam
2@Gabriel
3@Henry
4@Bob
5@Bill
```

So I want the data to be merged together separated by '@' in result.txt.

Any Help?Thanks

Comment: Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: Since I am not very familiar with python yet, I am pretty much stuck in the beginning only in how to write the code for it, the syntax, the flow control and everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, and unlike other answers I am not reading all the lines into memory here:

```
from itertools import izip
with open('text1.txt') as f1:
    with open('text2.txt') as f2:
        with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
            for a, b in izip(f1, f2):
                out.write('{0}@{1}'.format(a.rstrip(), b))
...                 
>>> !cat out.txt
1@sam
2@Gabriel
3@Henry
4@Bob
5@Bill
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Code comments in line:

```
data_one = []
data_two = []

# Open the input files for reading
# Open the output file for writing
with open('text1.txt') as in1_file, open('text2.txt') as in2_file, open('ouput') as o_file:

    # Store the data from the first input file
    for line in in1_file:
        data_one.append(line.strip())
    data_one = (a for a in data_one)

    # Store the data from the second input file
    for line in in2_file:
        data_two.append(line.strip())
    data_two = (a for a in data_two)

    # Combine the data from both the sources
    # and write it to the output file
    for a, b in zip(data_one, data_two):
        o_file.write('{0}@{1}'.format(a, b))
```

**EDIT:**

For python 2.7 and earlier, multiple `with` statement with multiple context managers are used as:

```
with open('text1.txt') as in1_file:
    with open('text2.txt') as in2_file:
        with open('ouput') as o_file:
```

Comment: I tried your code, it gives me the syntax error                       with open('text1.txt') as in1_file, open('text2.txt') as in2_file, open('ouput') as o_file:

Comment: with open('text1.txt') as in1_file, open('text2.txt') as in2_file, open('output') as o_file: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @sam You must be using Python 2.6 or earlier?

Comment: yes I am, can you provide a solution which would be compatible with 2.6 version?Thanks:)

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of using this: `data_one = (a for a in data_one)`?

Comment: I tried, now the error is different  -  o_file.write('{}@{}'.format(a, b))
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary I see your point. I was of the notion that it converts the list to a generator. But it is excessive already. I might as well just keep a reference to in1_file.readlines() ?

Comment: o_file.write('{0}@{1}'.format(a, b))
IOError: File not open for writing
Now this?

Comment: @sam Use Aशwiniचhaudhary answer. He has written the code taking python 2.6 into account

Comment: @shaktimaan It does creates a generator, but you already have a list in memory so what's the point of creating a generator now.  BTW that express is just equivalent to: `data_two = iter(data_two)`, Check my answer on how to do it in a memory efficient way.

Comment: I have used his code, btw thanks shaktiman. If I am not wrong that used to come back in early 90's right lol

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Thanks. But I remember reading that `iter` returns an iterator but does not convert a list to a generator?

Comment: Oh yes!! Late 90's. Anyways Thanks alot guys.

Comment: @shaktimaan You cannot convert a list into generator, you always create a new generator. You could have used: `data_one = (a.rstrip() for a in in1_file)` there, this creates a generator which is going to yield stripped version of each line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your answer:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as t1, open('text2.txt', 'r') as t2:
    with open('text3.txt', 'w') as t3:
        for row in zip(t1.readlines(), t2.readlines()):
            t3.writeline("%s@%s" % row)
```

Comment: You're not handling the newline characters at all.